# Ошибка создания события JS

Tags: javascript

Появляется ошибка при создании события click, через addEventListener. [image: Код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К тегу script добавьте атрибут `<script src="..." defer>` ?

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector` ничего не нашёл.
Попробуйте при подключении добавить `defer`, или обернуть всё в `document.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

Так как я не доглядел. Оставил класс .test. Хотя удалил его потом. Суть в чем. Заменяя test на i. Консоль ничего не выводит. Не надпись "Работает", ни ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так как btnAddContent создает функцию и помещает туда html блок, то и взаимодействовать с ним нужно там же. btnItemDelete нужно писать в стрелочной функции btnAddContent